# Autoresize called process within a panel C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have the following code that opens notepad within a tabControl panel, this works when I start the form maximized.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Tab Opening:

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage("notepad");

Panel tb = new Panel();
      tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

tp.Controls.Add(tb);
myTab.TabPages.Add(tp);
```

The problem is when I launch the form not maximized, opens Notepad then resize the form, the following happens (see picture link) --- notepad doesn't stretch out.

[After Opening Notepad within Panel the form is maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ec8d.jpg)

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 private static extern uint SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

 [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
 public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

 [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
 public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

 private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);

 public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;   
 public static int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER;        


 public static void loadProcess()
 {

   Process p = Process.Start("Notepad");
   p.WaitForInputIdle();
   p.Refresh();

   int WS_VISIBLE = GetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);            
   SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, (WS_VISIBLE & ~WS_CAPTION));
   SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
   ShowWindow(p, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);            

  }

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern
  bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

  private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

  private static bool ShowWindow(Process _Process, int nCmdShow)
  {
     return ShowWindowAsync(_Process.MainWindowHandle, nCmdShow);
  }
```

Comment: Be aware that reparenting windows that don't expect to be parented or otherwise forcing external processes to take part in your control tree really doesn't work well. If this is "I'll make it work with notepad, then switch to Xyz.exe", be aware that it almost certainly won't work. Notepad is one of the *simplest* windows applications and even it may start acting up here.

Comment: You must also pinvoke MoveWindow() to change notepad's window size, subscribe the tabpage's SizeChanged event.  Do beware that this is not a very good idea, this usage of SetParent() is depending on appcompat behavior for programs that used to run on Win3.  28 years ago this was not yet troublesome, the OS didn't yet have the notion of threads and processes.  You'll get away with it for Notepad but there are not a lot of programs left that are still primitive like Notepad.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant for the idea, it worked (MoveWindow and Form's Resize event) upon creating tabs but when I switch tab, it doesn't resize anymore. Maybe we need to focus first on the opened app within the tabPage so it would resize automatically. Any idea to set it focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few trials, I was able to resize it automatically.

On my loadProcess method, I have stored the process in a hashtable for reference later.

```
Process p = Process.Start("Notepad");
p.WaitForInputIdle();
sessions.Add(tabName, p);
```

on tabControl1_Selecting event:

```
 String name = myProcess.SelectedTab.Name;

 Process pHandle = (Process) sessions[name];

 SetForegroundWindow(pHandle.MainWindowHandle);

 SetFocus(pHandle.MainWindowHandle);

 MoveWindow(pHandle.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);
```

I've added a Form1_Resize event so it will resize accordingly.

```
String name = myProcess.SelectedTab.Name;
Process pHandle = (Process) sessions[name];
MoveWindow(pHandle.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);
```